# Does a Schengen visa issued and then cancelled have any effect on H1B?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

I am from India. I was supposed to go to Poland for business, but since the Polish consulate usually has a long waiting time for visa appointment, my company advised me to get a German Schengen visa, for which interviews/applications are processed the next business day after application, after which I could travel on to Poland for my business.

So, I did. But Lufthansa denied me boarding, as my country destination was Poland and I was carrying a Schengen visa for Germany. The next day, the German consulate called me over and canceled my visa for the following reasons:

1. Consulate was made aware Germany is not the primary destination.
2. Unreliable information was supplied.

Now, how serious is this? I really need to be in Poland. Will the Polish consulate even entertain my visa application? Should I make one?

Will this have any impact on my H1B visa stamping, which is due shortly? In general, how much of a special treatment am I going to get around the world?

Also, will traveling to other countries for business/tourism 'dilute' the seriousness of this cancellation, so it does not look like a grave violation of rules, which it was no? It was a bit dodgy but done with no fraudulent intent.

Comment: Just to clarify: Did you lie and provide a deceptive travel plan when applying for the German visa?

Comment: No - the travel plan was for Poland and I gave the tickets booked for Poland.

Comment: @Newton The linked question contains very useful relevant information, but it doesn't really seem like a duplicate, especially in regards to possible effects on H-1B.